# PowerShell script not referencing value stored in variable

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue getting the script to use the value stored in `$computername` variable throughout the entire script. This value is used to run commands on a remote machine on our network. The script only uses the value stored in the variable one time but the two subsequent if else commands are run on the local machine instead of the remote machine.

Here's the .ps1 script:

```
$computername = Read-Host "What computer do you want to check hibernation status for?"
Invoke-Command -Computer $computername {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power -Name HibernateEnabled
}

$hiberstatus = Read-Host "Would you like to change hibernation status for this machine? Use 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No."

if ($hiberstatus -eq 'y') {
    $hiberchange = Read-Host "Would you like to enable or disable hibernation? Use 'en' for enable and 'dis' for disable."
    if ($hiberchange -eq 'en') {
        Enter-PSSession $computername
        powershell -Command "Start-Process 'powercfg.exe' -Verb runAs -Argumentlist '/h on'"
        Exit-PSSession
    } elseif ($hiberchange -eq 'dis') {
        Enter-PSSession $computername
        powershell -Command "Start-Process 'powercfg.exe' -Verb runAs -Argumentlist '/h off'"
        Exit-PSSession
    }
} elseif ($hiberstatus -eq 'n') {
    exit
}

$hiberupdate = Read-Host "Would you like to confirm the changes made? Use 'y' for Yes and 'n' for No."

if ($hiberupdate -eq 'y') {
    Invoke-Command -Computer $computername {
        Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power -Name HibernateEnabled
    }
} elseif ($hiberupdate -eq 'n') {
    Write-Output 'Terminating powercfg sessions!'
}
```

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` does not doing what you think it is doing. To invoke commands in remote session from scripts, you need to use `Invoke-Command`. `Enter-PSSession` only affect where command from next interactive prompt will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
if ($hiberstatus -eq 'y') {
    $hiberchange = Read-Host "Would you like to enable or disable hibernation? Use 'en' for enable and 'dis' for disable."
    if ($hiberchange -eq 'en') {
        Invoke-Command $ComputerName {"Start-Process 'powercfg.exe' -Verb runAs -Argumentlist '/h on'"}
    } elseif ($hiberchange -eq 'dis') {
        Invoke-Command $ComputerName {"Start-Process 'powercfg.exe' -Verb runAs -Argumentlist '/h off'"}
    }
} elseif ($hiberstatus -eq 'n') {
    exit
}
```

Comment: Your changes stopped the command prompt window from showing up on the local computer but it seems like the hibernation status does not change on the remote computer either. Could there be something else causing the powercfg to not enable or disable as desired?

Comment: Thomas, what OS are the remote computers? are you admin on remote computers?

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I took the script inside of the Invoke-Command block and ran it locally on my computer and confirmed the hibernation status does change successfully. It seems to not want to run on the remote computer(s) when it's part of the Invoke-Command.

Comment: Bill, OS are Windows 7/10 Enterprise. I'm a domain admin.

Comment: So, obviously the machine you are running the script from, you are not logged in with your domain admin account, probably a local basic account.  If thats the case pass the invoke-command the -credential parameter with the credentials that have admin rights.  Also I found the site where you initially got your code, looks like that changed the command slightly for windows 10, you might want to verify that for windows 7 as well.  https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-or-disable-hibernate-in-windows-10/

Comment: Hi Bill, I revisited the site and modified the script but no go still. I can't even execute this on my local machine when I enter the local machine's name for the $computername variable. I am currently logged in as my admin account on the local computer as well (also the computer running the .ps1). I just tried adding -Credential to the Invoke-Command and no go.

Comment: Hello all, just following up on this. I've set up a test environment away from our network and still cannot change the hibernation status on remote computers using Powershell. Any help with this would be great.